# Get Rid Of Customize Layout Context Menu DevExpress

Tags: winforms, devexpress

When I right click in a blank space in my usercontrols or devEpress forms a context menu comes up allowing me to customize the form How do I diable this??????

I am working on a windows application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a DataControls property window Set AllowCustomizationMenu = False  on all DataControls on a form